# Disable scrolling in Osmdroid map

Tags: java, android, maps, osmdroid, openstreetmap

I have an [Osmdroid](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) MapView. Even though I have set

```
mapView.setClickable(false);
mapView.setFocusable(false);
```

the map can still be moved around. Is there a simple way to disable all interactions with the map view?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution. You need to handle the touch events directly by setting a `OnTouchListener`. For example,

```
public class MapViewLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    private MapView mapView;

    /**
     * @see #setDetachedMode(boolean)
     */
    private boolean detachedMode;

    // implement initialization of your layout...

    private void setUpMapView() {
       mapView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (detachedMode) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        // if you want to fire another event
                    }

                    // Is detached mode is active all other touch handler
                    // should not be invoked, so just return true
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Sets the detached mode. In detached mode no interactions will be passed to the map, the map
     * will be static (no movement, no zooming, etc).
     *
     * @param detachedMode
     */
    public void setDetachedMode(boolean detachedMode) {
        this.detachedMode = detachedMode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A simple solution is to do like @Schrieveslaach but with the mapView:

```
mapView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution is similar to @schrieveslaach and @sagix, but I just extend base `MapView` class and add new functionality:

```
class DisabledMapView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : MapView(context, attrs) {

    private var isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        if (isUserInteractionEnabled.not()) {
            return false
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
    }

    fun setUserInteractionEnabled(isUserInteractionEnabled: Boolean) {
        this.isUserInteractionEnabled = isUserInteractionEnabled
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

```
mapView.setEnabled(false);
```

Which should disable all interactions with the map view

Comment: Doesn't work for me